# What is the best way to export / import from source to target?

Tags: artifactory

We are planning to clone (make a copy) of our existing artifactory. our current setup runs artifactory on an EC2 instance with Derby DB and the files/artifacts stored in S3 bucket. In our copy we would like to have artifactory running on a new EC2, DB running on mysql and files stored in a different S3 bucket.
We have built a base setup for the target and its operational.
what is the best way to export / import from source to target. I see options for repository and system export. Should i do a repository by export/import ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A system export -> import is usually the recommended way.

You can see a detailing of the process in this [JFrog's knowledge-base - migrating Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/what-is-the-best-way-to-migrate-a-large-artifactory-instance-with-minimal-downtime/) article.

Also another entry with a video in this [How to migrate Artifactory from one environment to another?](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-migrate-artifactory-from-one-environment-to-another-video/)

However you choose to go, make sure to test well and backup before!

Comment: Thank you. I will try this out. Our source artifactory uses derby db and the target db uses mysql. Will this be an issue when I do the system export/import or is it intelligent enough to look at the system.yaml and use the mysql db when we import

Comment: Yes. It will. You have to make sure a DB exists before the import. See https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-move-from-the-derby-database-to-any-external-database-in-unified-platform-artifactory7-xwithout-losing-data/

Comment: Wonderful Thanks .. I will test.